# How to Select using Inner Join?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm trying to do the **INNER JOIN** using Query Builder. But when I try to retrieve this all in my tables it says missing argument 2.

> Missing argument 2 for Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::join(), called in C:\Users\JohnFrancis\LaravelFrancis\app\Http\Controllers\DocumentController.php on line 63 and defined

I don't know if my ALIAS is wrong or not but I just based on my SQL queries. See below.

**SQL**

```
SELECT D.title, C.category_type, U.username, DU.dateReceived FROM document_user DU
#1st JOIN
INNER JOIN users U ON DU.sender_id = U.id
#2nd JOIN
INNER JOIN documents D ON DU.document_id = D.id
#3rd JOIN
INNER JOIN categories C ON C.id = D.category_id;
```

**Result**

[image: Result]

**Database Diagram**

[image: SC]

**Controller**

```
public function showDocuments()
{

    $documentsList = DB::table('document_user')
        ->select('D.title', 'C.category_type', 'U.username', 'DU.dateReceived')
        ->join('users AS U')->on('DU.sender_id', '=', 'U.id')
        ->join('documents AS D')->on('DU.document_id', '=', 'D.id')
        ->join('categories AS C')->on('C.id', '=', 'D.category_id')
        ->where('sender_id', '!=', Auth::id()->get());

    return view ('document.show')->with('documentsList', $documentsList);
}
```

I wanted to retrieve but **EXCEPT** for the current user. As you can see here I added the **where** clause. `->where('sender_id', '!=', Auth::id()->get());`

**View**

```
<table class = "table">

        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Title</th>
                <th>Category</th>
                <th>Sender</th>
                <th>Date Received</th>
                <th>Action</th>
            </tr>               
        </thead>

        <tbody>
        @foreach ($documentsList as $list)
            <tr class = "info">
            <td>{{ $list->title }}</td>
            <td>{{ $list->category_type }}</td>
            <td>{{ $list->username }}</td>
            <td>{{ $list->dateReceived }}</td>
            <td><a href = "#"><button type = "submit" class = "btn btn-info">Read</button></a></td>
            </tr>
        @endforeach
        </tbody>

</table>
```

Comment: $this join( string $table, string $one, string $operator = null, string $two = null, string $type = 'inner', bool $where = false)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After reading a lot of blog and I find this lessons is useful.

http://jpcamara.com/selecting-carefully-laravel-joins/

```
$documentsList = DB::table('document_user')->select('documents.title', 'categories.category_type', 'users.username', 'document_user.dateReceived')
        ->join('users', 'users.id', '=', 'document_user.sender_id')
        ->join('documents', 'documents.id', '=', 'document_user.document_id')
        ->join('categories', 'categories.id', '=', 'documents.category_id')
        ->where('sender_id', '!=', Auth::id())->get();
```